# How can I embed SVG/PNG based on support without JavaScript?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to embed SVG images on a site. I'll be using Modernizr to detect SVG compatibility.
I've looked at SVGWeb and others and I don't really want to use them, for now.

What I want to do is:
If browser supports SVG, embed an SVG image in the HTML5 page.
If it doesn't, use the `<img>` tag to place a PNG alternative.

I want this image to be a part of the HTML and not add it via CSS's `background-image` property.

I also want the image and it's metadata (`alt` for img/`desc` for svg) to be easily read by Google therefore, I'm not sure if I should do this via JQuery.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using [SVG images in the <img> element](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20in%20html%20img)?

If you're doing this server-side, then there are a bunch of ways to do this, including [content negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) which may or may not work.

Alternatively, you could zip through all your images' src attributes and rewrite them with something like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var endsWithDotSvg = /.*\.svg$/
var i=0;
var l = imgs.length;
for (; i != l; ++i) {
    if (imgs[i].src.match(endsWithDotSvg)) {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.slice(0, -3) + "png";
    }
}
```

Comment: I read a whole bunch of articles and most of them said svg in the img tag was not supported...but those must have been outdated articles. I think I'll begin using the img tag now.

Regarding content negotiation, I don't know how reliable that is...must research that a big more.

Comment: I used a combination of both answers, actually:

    if (Modernizr.svg) {

        $('img.svg').attr('src', function() {

            return $(this).attr('src').replace('.png', '.svg');

        });

    }


Indenting by 4 spaces to display formatted code doesn't seem to work for me :/

Comment: @Housni Rather than adding a redundant classname to all your images you could use the CSS "ends with" selector: $(img[src$=".png"])

Comment: @HughGuiney, that's a good idea if I want to replace every single PNG's with SVG's.
However, there were some images for which I couldn't find SVG's so I ended up sticking with the solution I mentioned :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use JavaScript on the client-side then you are, ultimately, bound to do it on the server-side. What I could imagine is that you can check the UserAgent for which browser (& version) the visitor uses and display either SVG or PNG accordingly. Maybe that is an option?

Edit:
Okay, it seems you are still considering JavaScript.
Personally, I would opt with always rendering the img-tag pointing to a PNG. Then, when the document's ready, I would whizz through all of these img-tags and replace them with an embed-tag pointing to an SVG.

jQuery-Example:

```
if(Modernizr.svg) // Wohooo SVG words: let's party
{
  $('img.replace').each(function() { // Loop through all PNGs that need replacing
    // A unique identifier for images is saved in the id-attribute: use it to append the SVG version
    $(this).append('<embed src="' + $(this).attr('id') + '.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />');
    $(this).remove(); // Clean-up the unused img-tag
  });
}
```

Using the above example, an img-tag like

```
 <img class="replace" id="123456" src="123456.png"/>
```

will be replaced with

```
 <embed src="123456.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Maybe this works for you? ;-)

Comment: If I did it server-side, that would mean that I would have to maintain that code and update it with increasing browser support whereas a library like Modernizr would be maintained.

Right now, the only way I can think of doing it is like this:
    <code>
    <script>  
        if (Modernizr.svg) {
            //write an embed tag with an SVG in it
        } else {
            //write an img tag with a PNG in it
        }
    </script>
</code>

Comment: Sorry, can someone edit the above code? I'm only allowed 5 edits. I can't seem to get my code formatted as such :/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example :)
I ended up doing something similar after all, but I just used the replaceWith() method.

It's worth noting that it's better to specify the width and height attribute of an embed tag due to the way the various browsers render it.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I quickly threw it together as an example. So, yes: it's always good practice to specify height & with. I also left out the alt-tag which would render it invalid - as I said, just for the purpose of explanation.

IN any case: I'm glad you got it to work! :-)